# Reload index.html after post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to write a very simple web-app with express and node.js.
The app only has a index.html with a form. When the form ist POSTed, the node.js server should react by writing the input value in a txt file.
In the browser, the index.html file then should be reloaded to be ready to submit the next form.

I managed to get everything to work except the part where the index.html file is reloaded after the request is handled.
The index.html is located in the 'www' folder.

What is the best way to do it?

This is my app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static('www'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log('Express app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
})

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
   if (req.method === 'POST') {
        collectRequestData(req, res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
   } 
   // Here the index.html should be reloaded
});

//This function only writes the form data to txt-file, I don't know if it is relevant here
function collectRequestData(request, callback) {}
```

Comment: How are you posting the form?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try redirecting to the index after you handle the post:

```
server.on('request', (req, res) => {
   if (req.method === 'POST') {
        collectRequestData(req, res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
   } 
   // Here the index.html should be reloaded
 res.redirect('/');; --->Redirect to index here.
});
```

Here's the reference: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: With this solution "{"redirect":"/"}" is just outputted as string after the post request

Comment: Sorry, my syntax is bad, do you want to try this: return res.redirect('/');

Comment: updated the answer, take a look at the reference for other options you may want to explore

Comment: the "return" here is unnecessary, res.redirect('/') is all you need.